# div container with background-image position fixed

Tags: html, css

I want to create a page like this: [Page](http://www.lol-coaching.eu/)

I dont want to place the image as background. I want to create a div container and this div container have a background-image. And under this div should be a a other div. And if i scroll the div under the div with the background-image should go over the div with the background-image. I have something but it's crap.
Here my Page: [1](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/neuer%20Versuch/)

Here is the Code:

```css
*{
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://cdn1.editmysite.com/uploads/3/8/9/4/38945355/background-images/748028443.png') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: 50% 0 !important;
    background-size: auto !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    background: inherit;
}

nav{
   background: url("images/line-header.png") repeat-x scroll center bottom #4A525A;
   padding: 15px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   width: 100%;
}

nav > ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul > li{
    margin-left: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li > a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    color: #697683;
    transition: color 0.5s;
}

nav ul li > a:hover{
    color: #FFF;
}

.content{
    height: 1000px;
    margin-top: 500px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" >
        <!-- Open Sans -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div class="content">
                <h1></h1>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another `div` and set the `background-attachment` as `fixed`

```
.background{
  background: url('http://cdn1.editmysite.com/uploads/3/8/9/4/38945355/background-images/748028443.png') no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px; <------can make 500px instead of using margin-top: 500px on .content
}


.content{
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: orange;
  /*margin-top: 500px;*/ <-------------take out
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/h2oc09v3/)

Comment: Thanks thats perfect! And how can i change the height of the picture now? I want height: 100% of the picture. But the picture should not be streched. only the real height. As example the picture is 200px height and i dont want to write height: 200px. I want to write height: 100%, and the height is then 200px. I hope you can understand me :D And thanks for the answer! You get the green hook.

Comment: if you want the actual height and width just remove `background-size:cover` and that will leave the image the size that it actually is

Comment: Here is the new version: [Page](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/neuer%20Versuch/) But the height is buggy..

Comment: ? Could you help me pls? I want that the height= the real height of the image.

Comment: theres really no way of doing that unless your image is cut off in a way. The image just isnt tall enough. You could make the height fit but the sides will be cut off some

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68038/discussion-between-skeptar-and-jmore009).

Answer (score 1):

You might try this, add a image height of 700px and background-attachment: fixed;

```
*{
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    height: 700px;
    background-image:url('http://cdn1.editmysite.com/uploads/3/8/9/4/38945355/background-        images/748028443.png') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: 50% 0 !important;
    background-size: auto !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

nav{
   background: url("images/line-header.png") repeat-x scroll center bottom #4A525A;
   padding: 15px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   width: 100%;
}

nav > ul{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul > li{
    margin-left: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li > a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    color: #697683;
    transition: color 0.5s;
}

nav ul li > a:hover{
    color: #FFF;
}

.content{
    height: 1000px;
    margin-top: 500px;
    background-color: orange;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" >
        <!-- Open Sans -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div class="content">
                <h1></h1>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) Your answer is nice too, but in my case the other answer more helpful.